# Why is comparing a string to a constant failing to match, when the printed output clearly shows them to be identical?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, if-statement

I have a problem with my PHP loop in `foreach` and `elseif`, my code like this

```
foreach ($sth as $row)
{
    $std_kal = $row['code_std'];

    if($std_kal == 'a') {           
        $metode = 'A';          
    }elseif ($std_kal == 'b') {         
        $metode = 'B';
    }else{          
        $metode = 'C';
    }
```

if I run this code it will show `C` but value of `$std_kal` is `a`

Comment: Did you try to print the value of $std_kal?

Comment: Can you double check doing a var_dump($std_kal) before the if?

Comment: Can you show more surrounding code? This seems fine, how do you know it's 'a'?

Comment: only if  $std_kal is 'a' try something another than 'a' use 'b'

Comment: What is `$sth`? Sounds like a statement handle (as seen in perl), it's not the return value of `*sql_query()` or something like that, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look buggy.

Nevertheless, I'd propose this style:

```
foreach ($sth as $row) {

    $std_kal = $row['code_std'];

    switch( $std_kal ) {

      case 'a':
        $metode = 'A';          
        break;

      case 'b':
        $metode = 'B';
        break;

      default:
        $metode = 'C';
        break;

    } // switch

} // foreach
```

And a small remark: Instead of writing this

```
if($std_kal == 'a') {
```

I'd write this:

```
if( 'a' == $std_kal ) {
```

or even better this:

```
if( 'a' === $std_kal ) {
```

Why?

- The last comparison **compares values and datatypes**.
- The one but last **renders an error** if you incidentally typed = instead of ==. If you keep the variable left of the =, PHP silently assigns the variable...

Comment: thanx for ALL answers but after I recheck my SQL db table, I made wrong data type for it. I changed from char to varchar where with varchar, it will fixed-length and make wrong value characters when processed with php ;-)

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider using CHAR instead of VARCHAR. If all attributes of a table have a static length in mySQL, the record itself has a static length. This makes retrieving records faster, since the DB-engine is able to easily calculate, where a record is located in the table-file.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be right in case `$row['code_std'];` is a string or character ,try another value than `'a'` lets say `'b'` and the value of `$metode`  still  `'C'` then you must check the type of  `$std_kal` using this statement  `var_dump($std_kal)`  it's not a string or character .